# How to parse a string with multiple possibilities?

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm writing very much repetetive code lately. I need to come up with a better solution.

As for now I'm doing this (pseudocode)

```
std::map<std::string/*commandname*/, commandfunction*> Commands;

void OnPlayerExecuteCommand(cplayer* player, std::string command, std::string parameters)
{
    //find check blablabla yaddayadda then..
    Commands[command]->execute(player, parameters);
}

//heal PlayerId/Name (float)amount
void Command_HealMe(cplayer* player, std::string parameters)
{
    SomeParsingCodeA(params);//get the cplayer* from playername or id and float heal amount
}
//vehicle name color1 color2, eg /vehicle Ferrari 0xFF0000 123456
void Command_SpawnVehicle(cplayer* player, std::string parameters)
{
    SomeParsingCodeB(params);//get the vehiclename, and colors
}

//kick playername/id reason, eg /kick player_a you are spamming the chat
void Command_KickSomeone(cplayer* player, std::string parameters)
{
    SomeParsingCodeC(params);//get cplayer* of playername or id, and get the rest string
}
```

But each of the `SomeParsingCode*` snippets contains many repetetive code like `IsValidPlayer(string)//returns Cplayer from id or name`, parsing strings to numbers or floats or anything else..

I am thinking of making writing code easier by making a universal parsing function, something like:

`auto result = ParseMyParameters("Player_string_or_int;int_or_hex;int_or_hex",input)`
`if(result.good()){ //continue`

I was thinking of mapping each request to a character like:

```
character - expected input
u - PlayerName as String or PlayerID as integer(u as in user)
i - integer number
x - hex formatted number
f - real number
g - integer or hex
w - one worded string
r - return remaining string, 
    like /kick player_a you are spamming the chat
    would be parsed with "ur", and the result would be a cplayer pointer and the string "you are spamming the chat"
```

then making a function which loops a string and parses all the requested things one by one.

But I was thinking, C++ has so many good things, I really don't know what to use in this situation, which containers or boost/C++ includes can I use for this task? Is there something already in C++ which let's me do this? What approach is recommended?

Also, this will probably require some variadic arguments, use varargs or can I use some variadic templates? like

`ParseString<cplayer*,int,float,std::string>("Joe 5 5.0 hello my friend!");`

with

`std::string = "hello my friend!";`

or

`ParseString<cplayer*,int,float,std::vector<std::string>>("Joe 5 5.0 hello my friend!");`

with `std::vector<std::string> = {"hello", "my", "friend!"};`

?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is much easier using LEX (FLEX) or YACC (BISON).

You can use them to define your commands and provide actions when they are encountered.